# Passing data between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have two fragments, declared in separate classes - AFragment and BFragment. My MainActivity looks somewhat like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{       
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab firstTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Fragment A");           
    ActionBar.Tab secondTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Fragment B");

    SherlockFragment firstFragment = new AFragment();
    SherlockFragment secondFragment = new BFragment();

    firstTab.setTabListener(this);
    secondTab.setTabListener(this);

    getSupportActionBar().addTab(firstTab);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(secondTab);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    switch (tab.getPosition())
    {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AFragment());
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new BFragment());
        break;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, tab.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I pass a variable - say an integer - between my two fragments? For example, I'd press a button in the first fragment, and a particular integer would appear in a TextView in the second one.

Comment: You should tag this with `[android-actionbar]` instead of `[actionbar]` :)

Answer (score 2):

Fragments are meant to be re-used... that is, two fragments should **not** directly pass data between each other. Instead, you should define a [callback method](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) in the Activity. This will ensure that you can re-use your fragments elsewhere in your app (and in other apps you make) if you need to.

Comment: Thanks! I found the example they've given a bit hard to understand, though :( especially as I'm not using a ListFragment. Could you give me an absolute basic example, with, say, buttons? Sorry for being such a noob. :)